# specifying network ip docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I'm using docker to deploy a zookeeper ensemble and am running into a problem which I think is due to the proxy docker uses for localhost.

Edit: the issue is that while I am closing connections, they are left in TIME_WAIT

I want to change the IP for my containers to something else in the private address space E.g. 192.168.0.0 subnet and see if this fixes the problem.

Here's part of my current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
       zoo1:
               image: zookeeper
               restart: always
               ports:
                       - 2181:2181
               environment:
                       ZOO_MY_ID: 1
                      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888 server.4=zoo4:2888:3888 server.5=zoo5:2888:3888

      zoo2:
              image: zookeeper
              restart: always
              ports:
                      - 2182:2181
              environment:
                      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
                      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888 server.4=zoo4:2888:3888 server.5=zoo5:2888:3888
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/), when you start the docker daemon, you can pass the following parameters:

> --bip=CIDR: supply a specific IP address and netmask for the docker0 bridge, using standard CIDR notation. For example: 192.168.1.5/24.
>
> --fixed-cidr=CIDR and --fixed-cidr-v6=CIDRv6: restrict the IP range from the docker0 subnet, using standard CIDR notation. For example:
>   172.16.1.0/28. This range must be an IPv4 range for fixed IPs, such as 10.20.0.0/16, and must be a subset of the bridge IP range (docker0 or set using --bridge). For example, with --fixed-cidr=192.168.1.0/25,
>   IPs for your containers will be chosen from the first half of
>   addresses included in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.